# How to show orthogonality of the Laguerre polynomial $P_n(x)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials, laguerre-polynomials

At school, they ask me to solve this question:
For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x > 0$ we define

$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Sigma}\frac{\Gamma(t-n)}{\Gamma(t+1)^2}x^t dt$

where $\Sigma$ is a closed contour in the t-plane that encircles the points 0,1,...,n once in the positive direction (for example, $\Sigma$ could e the circle of radius $R>n$ around the origin).

(a) Show that $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

-> I have already shown (using te residue theorem) that this polynomial is equal to $P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!\Gamma(k+1)^2}x^k$

(b) Show that
$\int_0^\infty P_n(x) x^k e^{-x} dx = 0$   for $k = 0,...,n-1$.

-> I have already shown that this integral is equal to $\sum_{h=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n-h}(h+k)!}{(n-h)!(h!)^2}$, but from there I don't see that this will be equal to zero for the appropriate k.

Question c and d are related to this one I think. There they ask:

(c) What is the value of the integral above for $k = n$?

(d) Calculate
$\int_0^\infty [P_n(x)]^2 e^{-x} dx$

Can someone please help me with finding/proving (one of) these? Thanks!

---

Update:
For question (b), we can just use an approximation where we get that the integral
$\left | \oint_\Sigma \frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{\Gamma(t-n)}{\Gamma(t+1)^2} \Gamma(t+k+1)dt \right |$
will be less then $O(R^{k-n})$ for $k<n$.
Now (c) is the biggest question for me. I really don't see how to get there.

Comment: ... the (e) question being (repeat your title) "deduce that the $P_k$s are mutually orthogonal".